# Duplicate entry error when insert data into database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, duplicates

I am getting the following error.

Any solutions? I've already split up the database to 7 parts. And this is the last part I am having trouble uploading:

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `smf_themes` (`id_member`, `id_theme`, `variable`, `value`)
VALUES (17376, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', ''),
       (17377, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17377, 1, 'cust_twitter', 'aocsujbujp'),
       (17377, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', 'http://snapbird.org/'),
       (17378, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17378, 1, 'cust_twitter', ''),
       (17378, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', ''),
       (17379, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17380, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17380, 1, 'cust_twitter', ''),
       (17380, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', ''),
       (17381, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17381, 1, 'cust_twitter', ''),
       (17381, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', ''),
       (17382, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17382, 1, 'cust_twitter', ''),
       (17382, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', ''),
       (17383, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17383, 1, 'cust_twitter', 'cymjemqpmo'),
       (17383, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', 'http://www.viddyou.com/'),
       (17384, 1, 'display_quick_reply', '1'),
       (17384, 1, 'cust_twitter', 'izehcnqmsj'),
       (17384, 1, 'cust_fbc_pro', 'http://www.yourkindatv.com/
       [...]
```

MySQL gives me the error:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '1-17403-cust_twitter' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1):

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-17403-cust_twitter' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This simple means that you try to insert duplicate data.
Primary index is on 3 columns :

```
`id_member`, `id_theme`, `variable`
```

So to solve this, check your input SQL and remove duplicate data or modify primary key specification.